# how to get two object from websocket

Tags: javascript

I get via websocket a image stream for build a video

```
var frames = document.getElementById('frames');
var ws = new WebSocket( 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' );
    var reader = new FileReader();
    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            frames.src = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(evt.data);
    };
```

but when i send other object (JSON) to websocket, i have two object (image and json) the video starts to blink, how can i catch the objects separately?